# Is there an easy way to enter formulas in questions?

Tags: feature-request

I know math is not everybody's favorite, but sometimes you just don't get away without when designing a circuit for Arduino. MathJax is enabled on EE.SE; can we have that here too?

There are not many questions on the Arduino stack yet, but I invite everybody to add example questions that benefit from a MathJax below.

Comment: Yes, the way to request support for MathJax (LaTeX support) is to demonstrate a *need* for this in actual practice. As you suggested, the best way to make this happen is by compiling a collection of posts below which would *substantively* be improved with the addition to MathJax. If the benefit to *this* site can be demonstrated in actual use, we will bring it up for consideration. Good luck!

Comment: @RobertCartaino How to prevent "Trivial answer converted to comment"?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's an automated system. Add a bit of supporting text do describe *why* you think the post you linked would benefit from MathJax.

Comment: For the time being I use http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html You can place a button on your bookmark toolbar to enable MathJax on any page.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, a formula feature is needed. The Arduino has both hardware and software functions that are often best described as formula's when asking questions.

1. PID loop's
2. Filters

   1. often filters need to be calculated for the Hardware and then worked with in hardware.
   2. the PWM used with RC to make A2D can be best described with 2PiRC formula.
3. Polynomial
4. CRC's

   1. [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774794/how-to-determine-checksum-from-decoded-ir-remotes)
5. Motor control
6. etc...

Answer (score 7):

[Why do some pins have a different PWM frequency?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/210/why-do-some-pins-have-a-different-pwm-frequency/211#211)

Above mentioned question will benefit from MathJax. The formula when written without proper formatting quickly gets hard to read.

Answer (score 5):

Another perfect example why we want something trivial as the ability to author formulas is in this question:

[Why voltage at AREF is given by Vin * R2 / Rtotal](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/why-voltage-at-aref-is-given-by-vin-r2-rtotal/2977#2977)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one.  I posted basically the same question on both Arduino SE and Electrical Engineering SE.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307586/need-help-calibrating-adc-input-using-a-voltage-divider

[How can I seriously calibrate ADC voltage readings with Arduino Nano?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/38845/how-can-i-seriously-calibrate-adc-voltage-readings-with-arduino-nano/38854#38854)

The answer I came to in EE SE made good sense to share on Arduino.  I thought it was all one system but have discovered that each SE runs different software.

I havn't had time to remove the LaTex codes used to make it understandable on the SE one.  It looks really bad on Arduino.

The only option I have s to go back to the answer on Arduino and convert the equations to their FORTRAN equivalents.  Which I haven't yet done.

So I posted this question here:

[As we get more advanced in our use of Arduinos in ever more complex ways, it would be good if the Arduino SE supported Tex](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/as-we-get-more-advanced-in-our-use-of-arduinos-in-ever-more-complex-ways-it-wou)

I sure hope it can happen sometimes soon.

Here is the list of SE that allows it:

[Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax/216607#216607)

Answer (score 2):

With respect to the adage, "Go read the datasheet," datasheets contain formulae such as:

[image: Waveform frequency equation]

Figure 1 – Waveform frequency equation.

---

[image: PWM frequency equation]

Figure 2 – PWM frequency equation.

---

[image: PWM resolution in bits equation]

Figure 3 – PWM resolution in bits equation.

---

[image: Maximum external clock frequency equation]

Figure 4 – Maximum external clock frequency equation.

---

[image: Equations to calculate the ratio of the incoming data rate and internal receiver baud rate.]                   [image: Equations to calculate the ratio of the incoming data rate and internal receiver baud rate.]

Figure 5 – Equations to calculate the ratio of the incoming data rate and internal receiver baud rate.

---

[image: ADC conversion result]

Figure 6 – ADC conversion result.

---

Since the Arduino datasheets contain formulae, the Arduino forums should as well.

And here is one of many posts that would benefit from MathJax formulae:
[Switching a Solenoid Using Arduino's 5V Output?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/77602/68310)