# We need a way to create symbols in the Arduino meta

Tags: feature-request

I posted a question to the EE stack Exchange on how to put a horizontal bar above a character.

The [answer I got](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3878/how-do-you-make-a-complement-symbol) was to use MathJax, which I had never heard of. The markup in that post works perfectly in the EE SE, but not in the Arduino SE.

Can we get something like that for this forum? We're always posting about digital pins, and frequently need to interface with chips like ADCs, flip-flops, and clocked logic chips that have inverted pins like (not)enable, (not)busy, or (not)q (where all of those things should have a bar over them.

Seems like a facility for math markup would be a boon on this Arduino board.

Here's [the latest thread (on 16 bit ADCs)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/using-a-16-bit-adc-chip-with-arduino) where I needed this.

Comment: https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-there-an-easy-way-to-enter-formulas-in-questions/2446#2446

Comment: https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/as-we-get-more-advanced-in-our-use-of-arduinos-in-ever-more-complex-ways-it-wou

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax/216607#216607

Comment: https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/as-we-get-more-advanced-in-our-use-of-arduinos-in-ever-more-complex-ways-it-wou