# As we get more advanced in our use of Arduinos in ever more complex ways, it would be good if the Arduino SE supported Tex

Tags: feature-request

One user was kind enough to send me the list of SE sites that support MathJax (LaTex), and I see Arduino is not among them.

This means that when I learn something relevant on EE SE and want to use it on Arduino SE I have to reformat all the equations back to the basics.

I would like to request that Arduino SE add this capability.

Here is the list.  It sticks out like a sore thumb that Arduino is not among the dozens that can do it:

[Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax/216607#216607)

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-there-an-easy-way-to-enter-formulas-in-questions/2446#2446

Comment: https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/we-need-a-way-to-create-symbols-in-the-arduino-meta?rq=1

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307586/need-help-calibrating-adc-input-using-a-voltage-divider - compare the same answer in https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/38845/how-can-i-seriously-calibrate-adc-voltage-readings-with-arduino-nano/38854#38854

Comment: I know that Tex itself is open source, but the packages they use may not be free, like LaTex and MathJax.  I just hope somebody gets off the dime and makes it so we are compatible with the EE SE.  They have a lot to offer us.  Sure, they argue more than we do, but that's because they had to endure 5 years of college to earn the title of Electrical Engineer.  And afterwards a lot of them have had decades of work experience.  It is a great SE.  And all I want is to be able to copy (with attribution, of course), some of their solutions over here without having to convert it to FORTRAN.  ;-)

Comment: I just successfully got LaTex to work on a WordPress site, and it was free.  I used a plug-in called LATEX2HTML - same syntax as on the EE SE.  You can see it in action at http://www.sdsolarblog.com